# Dock freezing and right click and expose doesn't work

Tags: macos, dock, mouse

I don't know why, but there are some very strange problems with my system. At times, the right click will stop working on both the mouse and trackpad, only ctrl+click will work.

At the same time when pointing the mouse in the corner, it doesn't respond well. If I move the mouse over an icon in the dock, The dock will freeze, with the app icon stay "magnified". If I move the pointer over the dock, that icon stay larger.

I can click on any other icon, that don't move ( enlarge ) as usual and the app can be open.

I figured the only solution is to reinstall Sierra. (But, wait for it...)

I try to come back with Time Machine...nothing.
Disk Utility...nothing.
Bitdefender Virus and Malware scan...nothing.
I've tried to reinstall the MacOS but after two days the problem appears again.

I've tried to not use some applications in the background, but until now I can't understand if some of that cause the problem.

What can I do to determine and understand if there are some app that is causing the problem or if it's just my settings and data reacting badly with the code and system?

Comment: could you please tell us your version, and what computer you are using? - From Review

Comment: Sorry
I use MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
2,5 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: I've just noticed another issue.
Usually if i click on File in the menu bar and move the mouse to choose an option , every option become selected.
If the pointer go over , for example Open File..., it become blue for selected. When i have the problem, this doesn't happen. When i move over an option, that don't highlight . I know the is very difficult to explain

Comment: I want to add another information. After many try i've noticed that the problem start after a wake up from sleep mode. PLS i need some suggestion

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth mouse?
Disconnecting my Logitech bluetooth mouse fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/69629/100686):

> It looks like your dock has died. If you can get into Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal, I think), try `sudo killall Dock`. This'll crash-close the Dock, and it should restart happily. If it doesn't, logout and back in again.

Comment: Please give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Dock restarts bu problems are exactly the same.